# How to change display by document.getElementById inAngular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a scenario where I am generating dynamic elements with the data from backend some what like

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of datas" (click)="display(data.id)">

<div id="'full'+data.id" [style.display]=" active? 'block': 'none'">

</div>


</tr>
```

My Ts File

```
export class Component{
active=false;
display(id)
{
document.getElementById(`full${id}`).display="block";

}

}
```

What I want to do is something like above. I tried something like below but that doesn't work it throws error

> Property 'display' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'

```
 import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
   import { Inject }  from '@angular/core';

export class Component{
 active=false;
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document) {

   }
    display(id)
    {
    document.getElementById(`full${id}`).display="block";

    }

    }
```

any suggestions ,how to do this .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property 'display' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'

That's because HTML elements do not have a property `display`. What you're looking for is:

```
document.getElementById(`full${id}`).style.display='block';
```

Comment: No problem. Also that probably won't work because in your HTML the id attribute is not being compiled by Angular unless you add brackets like this: `[id]="'full' + data.id"`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than directly manipulating the DOM, the more Angular way of doing this would be to track the visibility state of each row and drive visibility through **NgIf**

> NgIf: A structural directive that conditionally includes a template based on the value of an expression coerced to Boolean. When the expression evaluates to true, Angular renders the template provided in a then clause, and when false or null, Angular renders the template provided in an optional else clause. The default template for the else clause is blank.

Here is an example with a single boolean driving the toggle of a single div, but you could do something similar with a map on your data.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-if-simple',
  template: `
    <button (click)="show = !show">{{show ? 'hide' : 'show'}}</button>
    show = {{show}}
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="show">Text to show</div>
`
})
export class NgIfSimple {
  show: boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: But how to do it with large data ,unknown amount?

Comment: I assume 'datas' is an array of JSON Objects. You haven't shown how you load in your data. However, when you load this data you could add a visibility property to each object and default it to true.

Comment: But I want it to be default false ,and my data is updating dynamically with setInterval so after ,some times it gets hidden :(

Comment: Then default you can default it to false. I'm sorry, but without more details this is all I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve problem like this:

```
let fullId = document.getElementById(`full${id}`) as HTMLElement;
 fullId.style.display='block';
```